# How to prove that this sequence is Linearly Independent over field K

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory

This question was asked in my abstract algebra assignment and I need help in proving the  assertion.

> Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and K be a field.
>
> (a) Let $x_1,...,x_{n+1}\in V$  be linearly independent elements of a vector space V over the field K. Suppose that n elements among $x_1,...,x_{n+1}$ are linearly independent over K. Then show that the Relational subspace over K, $$Rel_K (x_1,...,x_{n+1})=\{(a_1,...,a_{n+1})\in K^{n+1}\mid a_1 x_1+...+a_{n+1} x_{n+1}=0\}$$ is 1-dimensional over K.
>
> (b)For a given $n\in \mathbb{N}$ , let $a_1,...,a_n\in K$ be n distinct elements in a field K. Then the sequence $g_i = (a_i^v)_{v\in \mathbb{N}}\in K^{\mathbb{N}}$, i=1,...,n are linearly independent over K.

(a) I have done.

(b) I assumed that it be linearly independent over K.So, using (a) $Dim_K(Rel_K (g_1,...,g_n))=1$. I took $(b_1,...,b_n)\in Rel_K (g_1,...,g_n)$ a basis element of the relation subspace. But I am not able to find any contradiction.

Kindly guide.

Comment: If all $n+1$ of the $x_i$ are linearly independent, how can $n$ of them be linearly dependent?

Comment: The end of the statement is missing in (a). The "relational subspace" (first time hearing that expression) is... ? We don't know what you were supposed to show about it.

Comment: @CaptainLama I have edited it. Kindly have a look.

Comment: @No-One Can you address Arthur's comment? Something is off about your question

Comment: @Arthur It was a typo. Should be Linearly independent. Have a look now

Comment: @BenGrossmann I have edited it. Kindly have a look.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Can you please help if you have some time to spare?

Comment: @Avenger It suffices to use the fact that a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) constructed using a non-repeating sequence $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is always invertible